# Java Script practice - bundleArgsFunction

Tags: javascript, function, bind

I am relatively new to coding, and I have been doing some practice problems for javascript for the sake of practice. There is this one problem that I am stuck on about implementing the bind function. Essentially, I need to implement a function called bundleArgs with two parameters: a function fn to get args bundled with and args1, args2 to argsn - any numbers of args that will automatically get filled in when the output function is used. bundleArgs is essentially supposed to return a version of the original fn that can take any number of arguments, but when used, will use the args1, args2 to argsn as the first parameters to fn, filling in the new arguments afterwards. I attempted doing this with the bind function, since it basically makes your arguments pre-filled, however I am supposed to implement this WITHOUT using bind, and that is essentially where I am stuck. Example of the output: // example, you have a function that surrounds text with other text

```
function surroundText(surrounding, text) {
  return [surrounding, text, surrounding].join(" ")
}

// but you know you're going to use it for one thing only
const makeCool = bundleArgs(surroundText, "~x~X~x~")

// save yourself some time
console.log(makeCool("i guess")) // ~x~X~x~ i guess ~x~X~x~

// again w/ leftovers
function repeatLetter(letter, times) {
    Array(times).fill(letter).join('');
}

// fix 1 of 2 arguments to 'r'
rrrrrollWithIt = bundleArgs(repeatLetter, 'r');

// resulting function has only one arg now
rrrrrollWithIt(10) // rrrrrrrrrr
```

Comment: It will be good if you can add the code that you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? ^

Comment: I tried to basically use the .bind on the input function, but I came to find out they want me to do this without bind. This is kinda where I am stuck lol. Too dumb to start lol. @KarthickRamesh

Comment: Please edit your question and show exactly what you have tried. As you are new to coding, you'll find that it needs an exacting discipline. We need to know what you've done.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to coding :). Without something to debug it is hard to say where your issue lies, but it sounds like you are looking for an explanation of variadic functions. Try searching that and see if that helps you along, or maybe edit your question with some code so we can do more to help.

Comment: lol here is what I came up with bundleArgs(fn, ...argsn){                                     fn.bind(args) }

Comment: however, I can't use the bind function